# Raspberry pi 2 server does not respond

Tags: sockets, networking, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I have started a client server project with my raspberry pi 2 running windows 10 IoT which is very nice because you can run the same application on both the PC and the RPI2. With that in mind I only created one application that could act as both client and server which I then deploy on both devices and use one of them as server and the other as Client. The only problem is that server side never answers the clients connect call.

My code is as follows:

Server:

```
///servername is the port that I use
///hostadapter is an adapter helper obj that has a HostName property set to my Ip address.
public async void Start(string serverName, HostName hostAdapter)
    {
        //create the "server" object
        serverListener = new StreamSocketListener();
        serverListener.ConnectionReceived += ServerListener_ConnectionReceived;

        try
        {
            await serverListener.BindEndpointAsync(hostAdapter, serverName);
            Started = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            Started = false;
            myConsole.Print("error while starting server: " + ee.Message);
        }
    }

private async void ServerListener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {

        myConsole.Print("connection recieved callback called");
        DataReader reader = new DataReader(args.Socket.InputStream);
        DataWriter ServerWriter = new DataWriter(args.Socket.OutputStream);
        string ServerAnswer = "message recieved by server";

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // Read first 4 bytes (length of the subsequent string).
                uint sizeFieldCount = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));
                if (sizeFieldCount != sizeof(uint))
                {
                    // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data.
                    return;
                }

                // Read the string.
                uint stringLength = reader.ReadUInt32();
                uint actualStringLength = await reader.LoadAsync(stringLength);
                if (stringLength != actualStringLength)
                {
                    // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data.
                    return;
                }

                ServerWriter.WriteUInt32(ServerWriter.MeasureString(ServerAnswer));
                ServerWriter.WriteString(ServerAnswer);
                await ServerWriter.StoreAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            myConsole.Print(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

Client:

```
public async void Connect(string serverIP, string serverPort)
    {

        try
        {
            ServerHost = new HostName(serverIP);
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            //open socket
            ClientSocket = new StreamSocket();
            await ClientSocket.ConnectAsync(ServerHost, serverPort);
            Connected = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ClientSocket.Dispose();
            ClientSocket = null;

            myConsole.Print(ex.Message);

            Connected = false;
        }
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated. I have downlaoded wireshark to be able to monitor the networkdata and I have located the tcp [syn] package that the client sends, but I can´t see any tcp [syn ack] packages.

Comment: Can you try `BindServiceNameAsync()` instead of `BindEndpointAsync`?

Comment: I have tried both. I don't really understand the difference. I run with BindEndpointAsync() becuase I saw it in a microsoft sample.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, server works PC, but not on the raspberry, or does the server never works?

Comment: The Server works if the client and server both are on the same PC. As soon as they are run at separate machines they do not work. i.e PC client and server works. PC client, rPI server does not work. PC server and rPI client does not work.

Comment: Did you enable the local network capability?

Comment: Yes I have. Yesterday I changed from TCP (streamsockets) to UDP (DatagramSockets) and with UDP I can send messages from the RPI to the PC but I can not send messages from the PC to the RPI. I think that there are som windows settings issues. I did turn off the PC firewall, is there maybe a firewall on the RPI windows 10 iot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I was missing one capability. The capabilities that you need to communicate over ethernet are

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
</Capabilities>
```

I hade only added privateNetworkClientServer and internetClient..